# Cannot copy and paste in keikai

Tags: upload, keikai

I uploaded several files while testing [keikai.io](https://keikai.io/), but I noticed that copy and paste don't work in IE11. Is there any way to solve this issue? I find it working in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run keikai 1.0.0-beta.18 or later. Due to limitation of IE11 to access OS clipboardData; no way to copy spreadsheet 'format' from Keikai to 3rd party application(e.g. excel). In IE11, we support only copy and paste pure text in such case.